# Playframework ad-hoc form validation is executed but does not work as it suppose

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.2

I have `Login` class with `validate` method as follow:

```
public static class Login {

        /** The customer. */
        @ManyToOne
        @Constraints.Required
        public Customer customer;

        /** The password. */
        public String password;


        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public Customer getCustomer() {
            return this.customer;
        }
        public void setCustomer(Customer c) {
            this.customer = c;
        }

        /**
         * Validate.
         *
         * @return the string
         */
        @Transactional
        public String validate() {
            return "Global error";
        }



    }
```

Code for the form binding:

```
Form<Login> filledLoginForm = form(Login.class);
filledLoginForm.bindFromRequest();
```

when I validate form as follow:

```
if (filledLoginForm.hasGlobalErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.login.render(filledLoginForm));
} else if (filledLoginForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.login.render(filledLoginForm));
} else {
    return ok("OK");
}
```

view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="customer_id" name="customer.id" value="@customer.id" />


                                @inputPassword(
                                    LoginForm("password"),
                                    '_label -> "Hasło",
                                    '_showConstraints -> false,
                                    '_showErrors -> false
                                )
```

I get ok page, like there was no error, but in validate method I've declared it.

I use play 2.2.6

Comment: Please post the code how you do the form binding

Comment: I've posted. Is this what You mean? I don't have more.

Comment: Post also the view where this `Login` object is filled with data by the user. How is the customer being selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you check for this explicitely in your controller. Something like:

```
final String cId = form().bindFromRequest().get("customer.id");
if (filledLoginForm.hasGlobalErrors()
        || cId==null || cId.equals("")) {
    // in this case either there were some validation errors or the provided customer.id is not valid
    return badRequest(yourTemplateHere.render(filledLoginForm));
}
```

An alternative you can try is to rewrite your `validate()` method a bit and do the check there (assuming there is an `id` field in your `Customer` class):

```
public String validate() {
    return Customer.id != null ? null : "Oh no, the customer id is empty";
}
```

P.S. having public fields and setters/getters at the same time is a bit confusing - switch to either public fields or make them private and use the getters and setters